# Twilio throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to set up Twilio to send a text once a new item is submitted on my app. Currently I am getting a

```
POST http://localhost:3000/sendtext 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

while trying to execute the script through the app.

Here is what I have in my app.js:

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio.RestClient('twilio stuff', 'twilio stuff');

app.post('/sendtext', function(req, res){
    client.sendSms({
    to:'8888888888',
    from:'8888888888',
    body:'ahoy hoy! Testing Twilio and node.js'
}, function(error, message) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('Success! The SID for this SMS message is:');
        console.log(message.sid);
        console.log('Message sent on:');
        console.log(message.dateCreated);
    } else {
        console.log('Oops! There was an error.');
    }
});
});
```

And here is what is in my controller:

```
$scope.addTask = function(obj){
    obj.days = $scope.selectedDays;
    $scope.taskList.push(obj);
    tasks.add(obj);
    $scope.newTask = false;
    console.log(obj);
    console.log('addTask successfully called');
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/sendtext',
        data: {}
    })
};
```

This actually works through Postman. when I Post to the localhost location.

Comment: Even though the text gets sent, Postman does state that it could not get a response and that there was an error connecting to localhost.

Comment: This might be a bit hacky - but I did get it to work I changed my app.js to app.post('/sendtext', api.sendText) and created the function in my api.js and required twilio and client there. Kind of a bad work around, but it is working for the moment. For that matter, it is sending multiple texts now, about 2 minutes apart.